# Histogram not displayed properly in Kibana-3

Tags: kibana

The histogram i created with my data is shown as a thick block. There are valid hits numbers and dates on the y and x axis respectively, which indicates the data is proper. What can be done to scale it down to an understandable one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your histogram is that the data you have indexed would be having a good frequency against the date and/or the data might be months old. So the default interval option for Kibana is set to one year.

You can change it by changing the default time period from "year" to any other smaller values under the section "view" (marked as 1 in the below figure) in the "Interval" dropdown (marked as 2).
[image]
More on histogram analytics can be from this [blog](http://blog.qbox.io/advanced-kibana-analytics-part-4-of-series)